# Сброс состояния компонента

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Решаю задачу по написанию дипломного проекта. Недавно костылями и всеми правдами, неправдами пришел к такому коду.

```js
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import Registration from './components/Registration'
import Course from './components/Course'
import Theme from './components/Theme'
import Lesson from './components/Lesson'
import Qst from './components/Qst'
import Test from './components/Test'
import ShowLesson from './components/ShowLesson'
import ShowQuest from './components/ShowQuest'
import TestAnswer from './components/TestAnswer'
import QstAnswer from './components/QstAnswer'
import Delete from './components/Delete'
import {Router, Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import createBrowserHistory from "history/createBrowserHistory"
import './preload.css'



const customHistory = createBrowserHistory();
const btns = (
 <div className="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar" aria-label="Toolbar with button groups">
  <div className="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group" aria-label="First group">
   <Link to="/admin/add" className="course btn btn-secondary">ADD</Link>
   <Link to="/admin/delete" className="qst btn btn-secondary">DELETE</Link>
   <Link to="/admin/showlesson" className="map btn btn-secondary">SHOW LESSON</Link>
   <Link to="/admin/showqst" className="lesson btn btn-secondary">SHOW QUEST</Link>
  </div>
 </div>);
let header = new Headers({
 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
 'Accept': 'application/json'
}) 

let myInit = { method: 'GET',
    mode: 'cors',
    header: header,
 }
const endpoint = 'http://localhost:8080/admin/start';

ReactDOM.render(<div id="preloader">
     <div id="loader"></div>
    </div>, 
    document.getElementById('root'));

function getData () {
 fetch(endpoint, myInit)
  .then(res => res.json())
  
  .then((res) => {
   console.log(`Request to db`)
   let WrapperAdd = () => {
    const add = (
     <div className='container'>
      {btns}
      <br></br>
      <div className='mess'></div>
      <Course />
      <Theme course={res.course} />
      <Lesson course={res.course} data={res.ltheme}/>
      <Qst course={res.course} data={res.ltheme} />
      <Test data={res.ltheme} />
      <QstAnswer qst={res.qst} />
      <TestAnswer test={res.test} />
     </div>
    )
    return (add)
   }
   let NavBar = () => {
    const nav = (
     <div className='container'>
      {btns}
      <br></br>
     </div>
    )
    return (nav)
   }
   let DeleteWrapper = () => {
    const del = (
     <div className='container'>
      {btns}
      <br></br>
      <div className='mess'></div>
      <Delete data={res} />
     </div>
    )
    return (del)
   }
   let ShowLessonWrapper = () => {
    const sl = (
     <div className='container'>
      {btns}
      <br></br>
      <div className='mess'></div>
      <ShowLesson data={res.ltheme} />
     </div>
    )
    return (sl)
   }
   let ShowQstWrapper = () => {
    const sqst = (
     <div className='container'>
      {btns}
      <br></br>
      <div className='mess'></div>
      <ShowQuest qst={res.qst} test={res.test} />
     </div>
    )
    return (sqst)
   }
   
   ReactDOM.render(<Router history={customHistory}>
    <div>
     <Route path="/admin/showlesson" component={ShowLessonWrapper} />
     <Route path="/admin/showqst" component={ShowQstWrapper} />
     <Route path="/admin/delete" component={DeleteWrapper} />
     <Route exact path="/admin" component={NavBar} />
     <Route exact path="/" component={Registration} />
     <Route path="/admin/Add" component={WrapperAdd} />
    </div>
   </Router>, document.getElementById('root'));
  })
 
}
getData()
setInterval(getData, 7000)


export default getData;
```

Приложение будет интерактивными курсами. У приложения есть админка, в которой реализован функционал добавления удаления и просмотра существующих данных.
Чтобы данные обновлялись при добавлении, я использовал setInterval
Таким образом решил проблему, однако в последствии оказалось что есть и баги.
Баг заключается в том что есть компоненты отображающие скажем лекции введенные в базу, однако из-за setInterval, открытая лекция через 7 секунд закрывается.

**Код компонента для отображения лекции**

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
let $ = require("jquery")

let header = new Headers({
 'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
 'Content-Type': 'text/javascript'
});

class ShowLesson extends Component {
 render () {
  const ltheme = this.props.data.map((el) => {
   let c = el.lcourse
   let t = el.ltheme
   return (`${c} -- ${t}`)
  })
  const courseTag = ltheme.map((el, i) => {
   return (<option key={`lts ${i}`} value={this.props.data[i].ltheme}>{el}</option>)
  })

  function Req () {
   let lesson = $('#showLessons').val()
   let body = [lesson]
   let endpoint = 'http://localhost:8080/admin/showlesson'
    let myInit = { method: 'POST',
        mode: 'cors',
        header: {header},
        body: body
     };
   fetch(endpoint, myInit)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((res) => {
     if (res.statusEror) {
      $('.mess').text(res.message)
      $('.mess').removeClass('success').addClass('err')
      setTimeout(()=>{
       $('.mess').removeClass('err');
       $('.mess').text('');
      }, 2000)
     } else {
      $(".showAria").show()
      $(".showAria").text(res[0])
     }
    })
  }
  return (
    <div className={'container'}>
     <form action="" id="themeform" noValidate>
      <div className="input-group mb-3">
       <select required className="form-control" id="showLessons">
       {courseTag}
       </select>
       <div className="input-group-append">
        <button onClick={Req} className="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" id="addTheme">Show Lesson</button>
       </div>
      </div>
     </form>
     <div className='showAria'></div>
    </div>
    
  )
 }
}
export default ShowLesson;
```

не могу решить это ибо не умею пользоваться Redux и потому передаю свойства иерархически. 
Чтобы обновлять поля и отслеживать изменения в бд вижу только два выхода. Метод задания интервалов или же каким-то образом вызова функции родительского компонента из дочерних. Помогите разобраться.

Comment: Этот код изначально не соответствует "философии" реакта. По-хорошему данные лучше получать где-то внутри компонентов, а не заставлять реакт постоянно рендерть главный компонент. Без этого вы всегда будете терять `state`'ы после каждого запуска интервала. Реакт здесь бессмысленен.

Comment: А где у Вас setState?

Comment: я бы вам 3 поставил за такое использование react, не 2 потому-что хоть что-то написали :)

Answer (score 0):

Решил задачу очень просто. Хоть мой код и набор костылей, но я хочу уточнить что это мой первый опыт работы с React и Rest API. Приложение можно рефакторить и переделывать до бесконечности, но это дипломный проект, а защита уже скоро, потому я искал скорее костыль чем нормальное решение.

В React иерархия идет каскадом (от родителя к потомку) и если запустить функцию родителя в потомке, то ничего хорошего не получится, однако я создал функцию "посредника", которая и стала связью между дочерним и родительским компонентом.

```js
import getData from '../index'

function Refresh () {
 getData()
}

export default Refresh
```